# how to host python script in a Web Server and access it by calling an API from xamarin application?

Tags: python, api, opencv, xamarin, webserver

I need to work with opencv in my xamarin application .
I found that if I use openCV directly in xamarin , the size of the app will be huge .

the best solution I found for this is to use the openCV in python script then to host the python script in a Web Server and access it by calling an API from xamarin .

I have no idea how to do this .
any help please ?
and is there is a better solutions ?

Comment: You trade the size of your program for the need to transfer all your data over the internet to be processed.  Which is going to aggravate your users more: A one time large download to get your program, or slow reaction for **every** operation involving openCV because you have to send all the data to a web server and back to get results?

Comment: Or, worse, your user is someplace where there's no internet and your program doesn't work.

Comment: I don't need it to be fast or offline.

Comment: OK.  Cool.  Just asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your web server using Flask or Django. Flask is a simple micro framework whereas Django is a more advanced MVC like framework.